# In Rails, what is the best way to store multiple boolean attributes in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `House` that has many boolean attributes, like `has_fireplace`, `has_basement`, `has_garage`, and so on.  `House` has around 30 such boolean attributes.  What is the best way to structure this model for efficient database storage and search?

I would like to eventually search for all `Houses` that have a fireplace and a garage, for example.

The naive way, I suppose, would be to simply add 30 boolean attributes in the model that each corresponds to a column in the database, but I'm curious if there's a Rails best practice I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your 'naive' assumption is correct - the most efficient way from a query speed and productivity perspective is to add a column for each flag.

You could get fancy as some others have described, but unless you're solving some very specific performance problems, it's not worth the effort. You'd end with a system that's harder to maintain, less flexible and that takes longer to develop.

Comment: Agreed. If you like, it could be tidier to have all the booleans in a separate model belonging to house, like a house has_one :feature_set (or something), and the feature set has all the booleans. Then you can use a virtual attribute for some sugar, like in the House model def has_fireplace?; self.feature_set.fireplace; end

Comment: Thank you, Joshua and John.  John, are there big wins in creating a separate :feature_set model to store all the booleans?  Would you strongly recommend the separate model design?  Because if not, I think I'll just go with Joshua's "add columns to House itself" approach.

Comment: No, there's no real reason to separate things except for organizational reasons, just an option if you find your "house" model getting too messy.

Comment: The naive assumption is not always correct.  The most efficient way to structure this *for storage and search* can be bitfields.  Depends on the size of the data, and the variety of the queries posed.  Use an integer column to store up to 16 booleans per column.  2 bitfield (integer) columns would be able to cover 32 boolean attributes.  I never do more than 8 attributes per column though, so I would use 4 columns in this case.
See: http://www.railsbling.com/posts/why-use-flag_shih_tzu/

Comment: There are definitely marginally more efficient ways to do this from a computational perspective, however a novel scheme is going to be far less efficient from a use of developer's time perspective.

Answer (score 7):

For that many booleans in a single model you might consider using a single integer and bitwise operations to represent, store and retrieve values. For example:

```
class Model < ActveRecord::Base
  HAS_FIREPLACE = (1 << 0)
  HAS_BASEMENT  = (1 << 1)
  HAS_GARAGE    = (1 << 2)

  ...
end
```

Then some model attribute called `flags` would be set like this:

```
flags |= HAS_FIREPLACE
flags |= (HAS_BASEMENT | HAS_GARAGE)
```

And tested like this:

```
flags & HAS_FIREPLACE
flags & (HAS_BASEMENT | HAS_GARAGE)
```

which you could abstract into methods. Should be pretty efficient in time and space as an implementation

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [the flag_shih_tzu gem](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu/). It helps you store many boolean attributes in one integer column.  It gives you named scopes for each attribute and a way to chain them together as active record relations.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution.

You could make a `HouseAttributes` model and set up a two way [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) association

```
# house.rb
class House
  has_and_belongs_to_many :house_attributes
end

# house_attribute.rb
class HouseAttribute
  has_and_belongs_to_many :houses
end
```

Then each attribute for a house would be a database entry.

Don't forget to set up your join table on your database.

Comment: +1 In the past I've chosen this approach, because there has always been the requirement (at the time or later on) to add more features - it's only a matter of time before they ask for has_solar_panels and has_futuretech.

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to query on those attributes, then you're unfortunately probably stuck with first-class fields, if performance is a consideration. Bitfields and flag strings are an easy way to solve the problem, but they don't scale well against production data sets.

If you aren't going to worry about performance, then I'd use an implementation where each property is represented by a character ("a" = "garage", "b" = "fireplace", etc), and you just build a string that represents all the flags a record has. The primary advantage this has over a bitfield is that a) it's easier for a human to debug, and b) you don't need to worry about the size of your data types.

If performance is a concern, then you will likely need to promote them to first-class fields.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd agree that your naive assumption is correct.

If the number of boolean fields keep growing and growing (`has_fusion_reactor?`) you may also consider [serializing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize) an array of flags

```
# house.rb
class House
  serialize :flags
  …
end

# Setting flags
@house.flags = [:fireplace, :pool, :doghouse]
# Appending
@house.flags << :sauna
#Querying
@house.flags.has_key? :porch
#Searching
House.where "flags LIKE ?", "pool"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about something like this

You have a House Table (for details of the house)

You have another  master table called Features (which has features, like 'fireplace', 'basement' etc..)

and you have a joining table like Houses_Features
and it has house_id and feature_id

By that way you can assign features to a given house. dont know whether this matches to your needs, but just think about it :D

thanks and regards

sameera

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a TEXT column that you hold JSON in (say, `data`), and then your queries could use SQL's LIKE.

Eg: house.data #=> '{"has_fireplace":true,"has_basement":false,"has_garage":true}'

Thus, doing a find using `LIKE '%"has_fireplace":true%'` would return anything with a fireplace.

Using model relationships (eg, a model for Fireplace, Basement, and Garage in addition to just House) would be extremely cumbersome in this case, since you have so many models.

Comment: The disadvantage being, of course, that LIKE queries that start with a wildcard can't use indexes, so if you have an appreciable amount of data in that table, you end up with a full table scan per query.